# How to create a button for every row in a table?

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

I have a table and I would like to have a button in each row that will allow me to mark this position as returned.
I have tried to create a form:

```
data EndBorrowing = EndBorrowing BorrowingId
returnGameButton :: BorrowingId -> Form EndBorrowing
returnGameButton borrowingId = renderBootstrap3 (BootstrapHorizontalForm  (ColXs 0) (ColXs 2) (ColXs 0) (ColXs 10)) $ EndBorrowingButton
    <$> pure borroowingId
    <*  bootstrapSubmit ("Return" :: BootstrapSubmit Text)
```

and then just map it over a list of IDs, but it does not work. When I try to extract data from this form with `runFormPost $ returnGameButton` Haskell wants me to provide an ID (and when I give it some fake ID it returns this fake ID, and not the one that was a form parameter).
Is there a nice way to make a button for every row?

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] and add the actual error you're  getting.